# How to fix matplotlib and seaborn heatmap plot?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, visualization, heatmap, seaborn

I have plotted a heat map, using Seaborn and also Matplotlib.

In Matplotlib, the name of the ticks is ok, but I do not like the white lines that appear.
How can I disappear the white lines?

In seaborn, the name of the ticks is wrong, but I like the plot.
How can I move the ticks to the center of each square?
How can I fix the name of the ticks?  The best score is of 0.857 with parameters: 'clf__C': 100000.0, 'clf__gamma': 1e-05

But seaborn uses: 'clf__C': 1e-05, 'clf__gamma': 1e-05

```
Ranking of best parameters
RandomizedSearchCV took 5.58 seconds for 25 candidates parameter  settings.
Model with rank: 1
Mean validation score: 0.857 (std: 0.036)
Parameters: {'clf__C': 100000.0, 'clf__gamma': 1.0000000000000001e-05}

Model with rank: 2
Mean validation score: 0.821 (std: 0.048)
Parameters: {'clf__C': 10000000000.0, 'clf__gamma': 1.0000000000000001e-05}

Model with rank: 3
Mean validation score: 0.720 (std: 0.065)
Parameters: {'clf__C': 100000.0, 'clf__gamma': 1.0}

Model with rank: 3
Mean validation score: 0.720 (std: 0.065)
Parameters: {'clf__C': 10000000000.0, 'clf__gamma': 1.0}


MY CODE FOR SEABORN
# You can use this to generate a (5,5) array:
# scores = np.random.rand(5,5)


plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
scores = inner_rs.cv_results_['mean_test_score'].reshape(len(C_range),len(gamma_range))
ax = sns.heatmap(scores, annot=True)

plt.xlabel('gamma')
plt.ylabel('C')

plt.xticks(np.arange(len(gamma_range)), gamma_range, rotation=45)
plt.yticks(np.arange(len(C_range)), C_range)
plt.title('Validation accuracy')
plt.show()


MY CODE FOR MATPLOTLIB

from matplotlib.colors import Normalize

class MidpointNormalize(Normalize):
    def __init__(self, vmin=None, vmax=None, midpoint=None, clip=False):
        self.midpoint = midpoint
        Normalize.__init__(self, vmin, vmax, clip)

    def __call__(self, value, clip=None):
        x, y = [self.vmin, self.midpoint, self.vmax], [0, 0.5, 1]
        return np.ma.masked_array(np.interp(value, x, y))


 plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
scores = inner_rs.cv_results_['mean_test_score'].reshape(len(C_range),len(gamma_range))
plt.imshow(scores, interpolation='nearest', cmap=plt.cm.hot,

       norm=MidpointNormalize(vmin=0.2, midpoint=0.92))
plt.xlabel('gamma')
plt.ylabel('C')
plt.colorbar()
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(gamma_range)), gamma_range, rotation=45)
plt.yticks(np.arange(len(C_range)), C_range)
plt.title('Validation accuracy')
plt.grid(False)
plt.show()
```

MATPLOTLIB
[image: Matplotlib]

SEABORN
[image: Seaborn]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you don't show any code for the matplotlib plot. But the solution to get rid of the grid is to use `plt.grid(False)`.

Comment: Hi I have just added the code for matplotlib. And you answer works!